# Show that if series $a_n$ converges then series $(-1)^n a_n$ converges - True or false?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, education

Show that if series $a_n$ converges then series $(-1)^n a_n$ converges.

[image]

Is that true? A quick proof is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What theorems about converging series do you know?

Comment: @Arthur i think it's about alternating series test but i dont know  how can solve it. I tried limit comparison test but it didn't work because there is no limit for (-1)^n

Comment: I have replaced "sequence" by "series" in your title and added an exponent $n$

Comment: This question is asking you to show the monotone criteria in alternating series test is necessary.

Comment: Please note that the question stated in the title of this post is not the same as the question in the provided picture. One asks about the convergence of a sequence, whereas the other asks about the convergence of the partial sums of a sequence. It is very important to be careful and to draw proper distinctions between the two.

Comment: @ChrisCuster yes, it is looking similar. I think I should study Leibniz criterion. Thanks.

Comment: A quick explanation with details about the context of the question is much appreciated fake siggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $a_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$. As

1. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n} = 0$,
2. $\frac{1}{n} >0$ for any $n \geq 1$,

and

3. $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$ for any $n \geq 1$,

we know by alternating series test that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. However

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$, and this does not converge.

We have identified a sequence $a_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ diverges.

Please let me know if there is any clarification necessary.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking it is about alternating series test.